# How to check the current Hash algorithm of ASP membership service?

Tags: asp.net, hash, membership

By default, ASP.NET 4 uses the HMACSHA256 algorithm for hash operations on cookies and view state. It there any simple way to check the current Hash algorithm of ASP membership service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two places (that I know of) to look --

Check your web.config -- you can set the hash for your membership services there which would override the machine settings.

```
<membership hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">...</membership>
```

if this doesn't apply to you, then you can check the machineKey in IIS.

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-aspnet-configuration-management#TOC301270285

Comment: I checked the machineKey in IIS7, it said it uses SHA1 and there is no SHA256 in the Combobox. According to ASP.NET4 document, it uses HMACSHA256 in ASP.NET4 but I can't find it. So, it makes me confused. I saw the link you post, it shows ASP.NET 4.5 include the SHA-2 family in the Combobox. Do you know why I can't see the SHA-2 family in the MachineKey combobox in my IIS7 server with ASP.NET 4.0?